# Merging two tables with interleaving the result of select queries of both tables in a proportion

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, union

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Posts
(
Id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
Content TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Ads
(
Id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
Content TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I need to combine these two tables in a proportion and apply `ORDER BY` and `OFFSET`. `1` row from `Ads` table in each `10` rows from `Posts` table  Is there any way I can accomplish this?.

The final rows should be 10 posts - 1 ad - 10 posts - 1 ad. How can achieve the merging two tables with interleaving the result of different selects

Normal `UNION` will merge all rows without interleaving

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id, Content, 'Post' AS Type FROM Posts
UNION 
SELECT Id, Content, 'Ads' AS Type FROM Ads) AS sel
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `row_number()`:

```
select id, content, type
from (
    select id, content, 'post' type, (row_number() over(order by id) - 1) / 10 rn 
    from posts
    union all select id, content, 'ads', row_number() over(order by id) - 1 
    from ads
)
where rn <= 1
order by rn, type desc
```

The trick is to divide the row numbers of the `posts` table by 10 - so each group of 10 consecutive rows get the same rank. Then, the outer query sorts by rank, then by descending type. This puts the first 10 posts first (with rank 0), then 1 ad, and so on. The rank can also be used to limit the number of groups.

Comment: what is the purpose of the condition `rn <= 1`? Because with that condition the query returning only 20 rows maximum.

Comment: @Farshan: I understood you wanted just two groups (10 posts, 1 ad, 10 posts, 1 ad). If you want all groups, then just remove that condition.

Comment: Sorry for misguiding you. Your answer worked for me. Thank you :)

Comment: Just a query, What if there are no  more records in posts table to merge and I don't want the remaining ads as the last rows of the list?

Comment: To answer my above query, I just used the above query inside a cte and added the condition `rn <= (select max(rn) from cte where type = 'post')`.